# DeployStudio Kernel Panic

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, netboot

We have setup a DeployStudio server on a Mountain Lion server and also a NetBoot set on the server for deploying an image for a lab of about 70 workstations. We are in the process of upgrading them all to Mavericks.

After we run the workflow that installs the image we get a kernel panic screen and then the station allows us to move the cursor and continue the startup process (It is the traditional kernel panic screen but allows us to continue). No problems have occurred while using the station. The only issue that we have come across that may be related was when creating the NetBoot set through DeployStudio Assistant it gave us a Recovery Partition version mismatch error but allowed us to create the set anyways. We do not know if this is related to the kernel panic that occurs but it's the only thing out of the ordinary that is happening.

Is the recovery partition issue related or is it something else? If there's is more information needed I am happy to provide it. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the backtrace information from the .panic file. I removed what I thought would be not for the public eye.

> Anonymous UUID:  [Removed]
>
> Thu May 15 16:29:43 2014 panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80234b8945):
>   Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa4d1938b, type 14=page fault, registers: CR0:
>   0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000000ccc1023,
>   CR4: 0x00000000000606e0 RAX: 0xffffff80371c2000, RBX:
>   0xffffff8037e8d200, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff8112b93610
>   RSP: 0xffffff8112b92e00, RBP: 0xffffff8112b936e0, RSI:
>   0xffffff8112b93738, RDI: 0x0000000000000000 R8:  0xffffff80371c2420,
>   R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff80373ec5e8, R11:
>   0x0000000000000206 R12: 0xffffff80368def00, R13: 0xffffff8112b938c0,
>   R14: 0xffffff80371c2420, R15: 0xffffff80371c2000 RFL:
>   0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7fa4d1938b, CS:  0x0000000000000008,
>   SS:  0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code:
>   0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0
>
> Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff8112b92aa0 :
>   0xffffff802341d636  0xffffff8112b92b10 : 0xffffff80234b8945 
>   0xffffff8112b92ce0 : 0xffffff80234cebfd  0xffffff8112b92d00 :
>   0xffffff7fa4d1938b  0xffffff8112b936e0 : 0xffffff7fa4d1a5a9 
>   0xffffff8112b93a70 : 0xffffff7fa4d17311  0xffffff8112b93af0 :
>   0xffffff7fa4cd9134  0xffffff8112b93b20 : 0xffffff7fa4ce12aa 
>   0xffffff8112b93ba0 : 0xffffff802386f789  0xffffff8112b93bc0 :
>   0xffffff8023870d30  0xffffff8112b93c20 : 0xffffff802386e74f 
>   0xffffff8112b93d70 : 0xffffff8023498c21  0xffffff8112b93e80 :
>   0xffffff8023420b4d  0xffffff8112b93eb0 : 0xffffff8023410448 
>   0xffffff8112b93f00 : 0xffffff802341961b  0xffffff8112b93f70 :
>   0xffffff80234a6546  0xffffff8112b93fb0 : 0xffffff80234cf473 
>         Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>            com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily(74.15)[5FA5C6BA-AAB5-3557-976B-69133F3CBDCC]@0xffffff7fa4cc1000->0xffffff7fa4d0bfff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7fa3a51000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7fa4c2e000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7fa4957000
>            com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator(1.0.8)[F3C46CFE-A6A0-3021-BA37-1D1881128DF2]@0xffffff7fa4d0c000->0xffffff7fa50c3fff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily(74.15)[5FA5C6BA-AAB5-3557-976B-69133F3CBDCC]@0xffffff7fa4cc1000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7fa3a51000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7fa4c2e000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7fa4957000
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
>
> Mac OS version: 12F45
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT
>   2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: [Removed]
>   Kernel slide:     0x0000000023200000 Kernel text base:
>   0xffffff8023400000 System model name: [Removed]
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 1339164379624 last loaded kext at
>   42800815738: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs  10.0 (addr
>   0xffffff7fa5367000, size 348160) last unloaded kext at 144857580806:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI 621.4.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa3cfa000, size
>   65536) loaded kexts: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs  10.0
>   com.apple.nke.asp_tcp 7.1.0 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.12
>   com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.13.12
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.1.7f4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  124
>   com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer 8.1.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics 8.1.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X  7.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.4.7fc4
>   com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator    1.0.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight   170.3.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.3d0
>   com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl   3.4.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.11d1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.6.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.1.11
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB  8.1.6
>   com.apple.nke.webcontentfilter    5
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage    345
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages.SparseDiskImage   345
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore  345
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore   345
>   com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    3.5.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   3.3.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    320.15
>   com.apple.driver.XsanFilter   404
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.3.5
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.BootCache   34 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 635.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI  4.9.9
>   com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  3.6.2b4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.6.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 621.4.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient   214.0.0
>   com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 4.0.39
>   com.apple.security.quarantine 2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 214.0.0
>   com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword   1.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 86.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily   10.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib   2.4.7fc4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.2fc7
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.12
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.1.7f4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily   74.15
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP  2.2.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.4.7fc4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.4.7fc4 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC  3.1.5d4
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy   1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.4.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.7
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.4.1d13
>   com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller  8.1.6 com.apple.kext.AMDSupport 8.1.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.11d1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink  1.2.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.3.7
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked  345
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDMouse 175.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse    175.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard  170.2.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 170.2.4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    3.5.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.7.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.5.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 2.5.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  2.5.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  2.5.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   1.3.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.5.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.5.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.5.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    623.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 621.4.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    621.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  1.9.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   2.7.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   630.4.4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily  4.5.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.2b1
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.5.1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   635.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
>   com.apple.security.sandbox    220.3 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    7 com.apple.driver.DiskImages   345
>   com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    28.21
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.8 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

Comment: Please provide the backtrace of the kernel panic, as much of the system log as you can, and a list of kernel extensions `launchctl list` - please examine the material before posting and redact anything that the public shouldn't see. Thanks.

Comment: I added the backtrace information. The problem only happens once on first boot up then it doesn't occur on startups.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one panic, don't worry. As they pile up, you can follow the general advice on troubleshooting kernel panics: [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean)

Once you have 5 to 20 reports, it's often far easier to know what piece of information in the long reports is relevant or repeats.